# Symfony / Encore : twig filter encore_entry doesn’t resolve the link {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}

Tags: symfony, twig, webpack-encore

I’m on a new symfony 5 project, with Webpack/encore and sass loader enable.
I also use symfony/apache-pack, so I’m use the following link to access on my web site :

https://localhost/myproject/public/show

I also installed bootstrap, with npm, and I import this css in the sass file : \myproject\assets\styles\app.scss   with :

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

When I run a yarn encore dev there are no warning, the css file is in the following directory (with bootstrap inside) :

\myproject\public\build\

My problem is these :

when I use the normal link (I’m on windows with XAMPP) : https://localhost/myproject/public/show , in my twig template, the following twig command doesn’t work :

```
 {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

links are broken :

[image]

I’m required to use for downloading the .css and .js files :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('./build/app.css') }}">
```

It is very strange, because, when I’m using the internal PHP symfony server (symfony server:start)
I use this URL : https://127.0.0.1/show , and the css could be load.

I don't edit the webpack.config.js  (except enabling the sass loader)

Someone can help me, please ?

Comment: Running Symfony on XAMPP/WAMPP is a pain, best to setup a **virtual host** for the project.

Comment: yes I know, but it's a constraint for me, I can't change this way to do

Comment: You may want to try building two Webpack configs with one having the adjusted public path, being conditionally loaded when on XAMPP check this out: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html#defining-multiple-webpack-configurations

Comment: You need to edit webpack.config.js and change the line `.setPublicPath('/build')` to match your public url: `.setPublicPath('/myproject/public/build')`. If your `prod` environment has its own virtualhost you can use something like: `.setPublicPath(Encore.isProduction() ? '/build' : '/myproject/public/build')`. If you have to support more environments you might want to look into other solutions...

Comment: thank you very much msg, it is working. I learn an important thing because of you, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

you must set `setPublicPath` in 'wbpack.config.js' file to `setPublicPath('/show/build')`